# LIMIT doesn't work in MariaDB - Tried a lot of things

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

```
$dbhost = "localhost";  
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "igscript";
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$query = "SELECT * FROM lastsearches";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("DB Error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " ( " .mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
}   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lastsearches Order By data DESC LIMIT 1;";
    echo '<center><p>'.$row["name"].'</p> </center><hr>';
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        die('Error : '.mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Whenever i use either LIMIT 1, or LIMIT 10; at $query, it has no effect at all. Still displays the same amount of rows. I tried also TOP 10 or TOP(10) as I seen on internet, and i'm getting

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '10 name FROM lastsearches Order By data DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 10 name FROM lastsearches Order By data DESC";
```

-> this was the query;
Also the first query worked properly in phpmyadmin, section SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query from which you are actually displaying results is this one:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM lastsearches";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

If you want to limit the results, you need to edit that query instead i.e.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM lastsearches Order By data DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the query in your while loop, but it is not doing anything inside that loop so you can probably remove it.

Comment: @bogdaNNN it looks like you extracted all the relevant parts into your question, so I think my answer is valid. Have you tried changing the code as I suggest?

Comment: Yes, i tried, now it's good. But what if i'll want to insert something in the DB with the same query? What should I do?

Comment: @bogdaNNN that should be a new question as it will require more information than you can realistically put in a comment

Answer (score 0):

`TOP 10` is SQL Server syntax, not MySQL.  MySQL uses `LIMIT 10` with a very similar effect.

Since I don't see `TOP 10` in your code, could it be some interface package that is tied to SQL Server?